# How to add a CSS-styled round close-button into the corner of a modal panel in sencha touch

Tags: panel, modal-dialog, sencha-touch

How could I add a round close-button (white circle with black X) into the upper right corner of a modal panel in sencha touch?

thnx!

edit: ...like the [FANCYBOX](http://fancybox.net/) is using.

edit: i found [this plugin](http://www.swarmonline.com/2011/01/ext-ux-panelaction-add-action-buttons-to-floating-sencha-touch-panels/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o.k, have to answer own question: i found this [plugin](http://www.swarmonline.com/2011/01/ext-ux-panelaction-add-action-buttons-to-floating-sencha-touch-panels/)!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a *Toolbar* with the *Button* to the *dockedItems* of the modal *Panel*, configure the *Toolbar* to have the position of *dock:top*.

Give the *Button* a specific css class using it's *cls* attribute.

Comment: yes, thanx - but I want it to look like the apple styled black circle without toolbar, "floating" in the corner...

Comment: the black border of the box should not grow at the top where the button-item is docked...